# How can I serialize torch tensor filled with complex number?

Tags: python, json, tensor, torch

I have some data like this:

```
tensor([[0.9938+0.j, 0.1109+0.j],
        [1.0000+0.j, 0.0000+0.j],
        [0.9450+0.j, 0.3272+0.j],
        [0.9253+0.j, 0.3792+0.j],
        [0.9450+0.j, 0.3272+0.j],
        [0.9028+0.j, 0.4300+0.j],
        [0.8776+0.j, 0.4794+0.j],
        [0.9253+0.j, 0.3792+0.j],
        [0.9253+0.j, 0.3792+0.j],
        [0.9985+0.j, 0.0555+0.j]])
```

and I would like to save those data into a JSON file.
I have tried to convert it to string by doing `data.numpy().tostring()` but it gave me an error saying `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`.

Is there a way to write it into JSON and later read it back?

Answer (score 2):

Hi pytorch can save dictionaries using the save and you can load with .load

heres an example:

```py
import torch

save_dict = {
   "test": torch.randn(1, 100),
   "test2": torch.zeros(100),
   "test3": torch.ones(100)
}

torch.save(save_dict, 'test.pt')
torch.load('test.pt')
```